# Can a Druid Wild Shape into a non-core elemental?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, house-rules

I have a party with a level 10 druid, and she was told she can transform into any elemental.

When the party was injured after a particularly tough encounter, she transformed into Positive Energy Elemental and started making non-lethal touch attacks to the party members, effectively healing them 1d6 health per action (She transformed into a medium elemental, since I wasn't sure, I just made it 1 size smaller for non-core elementals).

Given that this effectively translates to 5 full party heals a day, I am hesitant about whether this is a legal course of action. I know I allowed it once, so I should probably stick with it, but for future campaigns, is this legal?

Assuming I disallow changing into 3rd-Party creatures, which this elemental is, is it advisable that I allow Wild Shaping into non-core elementals, like Ice and Lightning?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Officially, the [druid](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid) can't use [wild shape](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid#TOC-Wild-Shape-Su-) to assume such a form...

The [druid](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid) supernatural ability [wild shape](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid#TOC-Wild-Shape-Su-) allows the druid to use an effect duplicating the spell [*elemental body*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/elemental-body) I at druid level 6, *II* at level 8, *III* at level 10, and *IV* at level 12.

The spell [*elemental body*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/elemental-body) has no provision for elementals other than air, earth, fire, and water. Of the elementals listed on the *d20 Pathfinder SRD* that I looked at ([cold iron](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/elemental/elemental-cold-iron), [gravity](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/elemental/elemental-gravity-tohc), [lightning](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/elemental/elemental-lightning), [time](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/elemental/elemental-time-tohc), and, to make sure, [positive energy](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/elemental/elemental-positive-energy-tohc)), none address nor alter the spell *elemental body*.

If the GM allows the druid to take such nonstandard forms and gain such nonstandard abilities, these are house rules, and the GM should make it clear to all players that they are house rules and explain how they work.

Expanding the druid's wild shape abilities in this way is something *Pathfinder* deliberately shut down in an effort to make druids *less* powerful, druids having been among the most powerful classes in *Pathfinder*'s antecedent, *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5*.

#### ...But house rules can make it happen anyway

First, the GM should look at the *elemental body* spells and provide details as to what effects assuming the elemental body of an nontraditional elemental has. Then the GM can create for the campaign a custom feat, magic item, or spell that allows assuming nontraditional elemental bodies. (However, unless the abilities granted by the nontraditional elementals are vastly superior to the traditional, once the details are hashed out, it's perfectly reasonable for mere familiarity (as suggested by GnoveltyGnome's now deleted [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/67582/8610)) to be sufficient for assuming those forms.)

Comment: My answer was wrong, I didn't have the time to look up Elemental Body before I left work. I deleted mine in favor of this, the correct answer.

Comment: I feel like it *should* be possible to find an acceptable level of *elemental body* for each elemental.

Comment: @KRyan Probably, but the *druid* doesn't need that. The druid's already getting a supernatural version of *elemental body* 1 level earlier than the spell, multiplying the duration by 60 (!), and gaining free uses per day equal to (1/2 level -1; exception: 20th). The *spell* is good enough *now* to merit serious consideration from a wizard (albeit as a third or fourth pick). However, I'd certainly let a caster research a custom spell like *elemental body* for nontraditional elementals.

Comment: Thanks for the clear and concise answer. I had forgotten to take into account the rules for crafting your own spell. That is probably the answer I will be using in further campaigns.